# Bing Custom Search Engine

Tags: bing, bing-api

What parameters should I use in order to get search result from only a site say abcd.com using bing 2.0 API? I am trying to fetch results in JSON format. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

fresh code to the masses

```
            $query = array
        (
            'AppId' => <API_KEY>,
            'sources' => 'Web',
            'query' => 'site:www.tipografix.ro '.$keywords,
            'Version' => '2.0',
            'Options' => 'EnableHighlighting',
            'Web.Count' => $per_page,
            'Web.Offset' => $page_num,
            'Web.Options' => 'DisableHostCollapsing DisableQueryAlterations'
        );

        $request = 'http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?'.http_build_query($query);

        $response  = file_get_contents($request);
        $jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the JSON format of the API works but in the *query* parameter put in "site:abcd.com bacon" where *bacon* is your original query.

I'm using the XML format so if I'd send a request to:

```
http://api.search.live.net/xml.aspx?Appid=________&query=site%3Aabcd.com+bacon&sources=web&web.count=5&web.offset=0
```